# delete record from two different table using one query Mysql

Tags: mysql

i want to delete record from two table which is relate by f key.
this is sample code the way i use in my original code. but this is not working.

DELETE from tb_extensions ext
inner JOIN tb_employee em
on em.emp_id = ext.emp_id
where tb_employee.emp_id = 'new1'

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`DELETE ext,em from tb_extensions ext inner JOIN tb_employee em on em.emp_id = ext.emp_id where tb_employee.emp_id = 'new1';`

Comment: this code also given error for inner join as UNEXPECTED KEYWORD

Comment: Why do you even need to delete from both tables by sql statement? If you have foreign key in child table, use ON DELETE CASCADE and delete from master table only.
Please share your create table scripts.

Comment: Although query ran fine for me. Could you please share some more details about how are you executing the query? You are using MySql server...right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be this works as you expected.

```
DELETE FROM tb_extensions, tb_employee USING tb_extension INNER JOIN 
tb_employee WHERE tb_employee.emp_id = 'new1'
AND tb_employee.emp_id = tb_extensions.emp_id
```